# Why can't I see environment variables, that has been set via "os.environ[]"

Tags: python, environment-variables

I use python 3.6 os.environ[] to set/get variables. 
My question is - why the Linux command #pritenv does not show these variables? 
Here is the example:

```
[root@server ~ 508]$cat test.py       
import os
os.environ['foo'] = 'bar'
print(os.environ['foo'])
[root@server ~ 509]$
[root@server ~ 509]$
[root@server ~ 509]$python3.6 test.py       
bar
[root@server ~ 510]$printenv | grep foo
[root@server ~ 511]$ ((nothing))
```

Comment: Despite the imagery suggested by the name, "environment variables" don't live in some sort of shared environment. Each process has their own, and a Python process setting its own environment variables won't affect the environment variables of the shell you launched it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of how processes and environment variables work in Linux (and most other operating systems). Each process inherits environment variables from its parent process, but doesn't (and cannot) impact its parent's environment. Specifically, in your case you have:

- sh (or some other shell), with some environment variables (e.g. X, Y, Z).

  - Python, which creates a new environment variable 'foo', and then dies.
  - `printenv`, which prints all its environment variables, which are the ones it got from its parent - the shell.

Comment: I am so sorry that I asked this question. Cause I used to know it definitely and then forgot. Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables modify the environment of the current process. Here's an example

```
% echo $SO_EXAMPLE # No value here

% bash # Start a new shell
$ SO_EXAMPLE="something"
$ echo $SO_EXAMPLE # It's available here
something
$ bash # start a new shell
$ echo $SO_EXAMPLE # Nothing here since it was not exported

$ exit # Go back to the parent shell
exit
$ export SO_EXAMPLE #Export the variable
$ bash # Start a new shell
$ echo $SO_EXAMPLE #It's visible here
something
$ exit # Go back to the parent shell
exit
$ exit # Go back to the original shell
exit
% echo $SO_EXAMPLE # Still nothing here. Even if it was exported.
```

So, even if you modify the environment, your parent environment won't be affected. In your case, the second is a Python process  but the logic is similar.